# eUML2 for Eclipse: Association Link Types

Tags: eclipse, uml

I'm trying to find out what different types of association links are available in eUML2 for Eclipse - is there any official documentation which explains it? I've been looking for an hour or so and had no luck so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think eUML2 uses the org.eclipse.uml2 metamodel. If this is true, it should support all association kinds from the UML 2.4 infrastructure. Namely these are Association, Association Class, Composition, Aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

The association is saved in the java code as tags. You can draw associations graphically and see the tag in the code.
There no model explorer visible therefore only the java code can give this association information.